# Django- invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I added 'Kurdish' language to my django website. this language is not supported by django, so I added to languages as follow:
in settings.py

```
gettext = lambda s: s
NEW_LANG_INFO = {
    'ku': {
       'bidi': True,
       'code': 'ku',
       'name': 'Kurdish',
       'name_local': u'کوردی',
    },
}

import django.conf.locale
LANG_INFO = dict(**django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO, **NEW_LANG_INFO)
django.conf.locale.LANG_INFO = LANG_INFO

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', 'English'),
    ('ku', gettext('Kurdish')),
    ('ar', 'Arabic')
)
```

now when i go to `mysite.com/en/admin/` it works properly. when I go to `mysite.com/ar/admin/` it works properly.
but when I go to `mysite.com/ku/admin/` it raises an error with this message:
`ValueError at /ku/admin/
 invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION`

the django version is `1.11.6`.

what's the problem and how can i solve it?

**Update**
I find that in django.po in `locale/ku/LC_MESSAGES`, the last line of comments is `"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"`

Comment: concider reading through [this](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html)

Answer (score 7):

Here is also an answer to the same error, but a different case (their language is supported):

[French translation raises "ValueError('invalid token in plural form: %s' % value)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545202/french-translation-raises-valueerrorinvalid-token-in-plural-form-s-value)

Maybe somebody finds that helpful. I was also searching for help and found your problem, but my solution was on the link above.
(**Solution** was to delete the projects virtual environment and install it again)

Answer (score 5):

I have written a more comprehensive answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545202/french-translation-raises-valueerrorinvalid-token-in-plural-form-s-value/61474435#61474435).

For short if your language has just one form for plurals for example, for more than two `apple` you say `apples`, find this line:

```
 "Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

and change it to:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

AND also you need to delete and setup your env again.

Comment: and dont forget to recompile your messages.