# French translation raises "ValueError('invalid token in plural form: %s' % value)"

Tags: django, internationalization

I want to handle a french version of my website.

I use Django 2.2 with i18n and I already set locale variables in settings.py.

```py
# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

When I use `./manage.py makemessages -l fr`, I correctly have a django.po french file but after `./manage.py compilemessages -l fr` the server crashes with the following error (trimed) :

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/gettext.py", line 93, in _tokenize
    raise ValueError('invalid token in plural form: %s' % value)
ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION
```

English, Italian and Spanish translations work well

**EDIT :** Well, the issue has been resolved, but I'm not really sure how. I deleted my `venv`, recreated it and french translation suddenly worked. Upgrading from Django 2.2.1 to 2.2.2 may be what caused the resolution.

Comment: Same here. Purging the venv folder worked as well.

Comment: Me too. Thank you guys. I deleted the virtual envirnonment, installed a new one, and all works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

For other language facing this error:

There exists a line that tells Django evaluating this expression, decide which form of the word it should use, and for some languages, this expression is not written, e.g. Farsi.

For these languages, a default line is written in your main .po file(not the specific ones):

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

Here the `EXPRESSION` part should be changed to your language.

[HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/gettext) you can read the exact format of EXPRESSION, but for short if your language has just two forms for singular and plural form change the line to this:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

And recompile your messages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The reason was that i accidentally wrote a word in messages.po file in configuration lines (that are on top of .po file, containing "Project-Id-Version", "Plural-Forms", ...)

So i checked what changes i made with my VSC (git) and it was fixed.
Don't forget to recompile your .mo files