# Compiling "en_US" gets "ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION" in Django

Tags: python, django, compilation, translation, django-i18n

In `settings.py`, by default, `en-us` is set to [LANGUAGE_CODE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#language-code) so I also set `en-us` to [LANGUAGES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#languages) as shown below, then there is no error. *I'm learning [Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/) with **Django 4.2.1**:

```py
# "settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # ...
]

# ...

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = [
   BASE_DIR / 'locale',
]

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', _('English')), # Here
)
```

Then, I ran [makemessages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#makemessages) below to create `django.po` in `locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/`:

```
django-admin makemessages -l en_US
```

But, after I ran [compilemessages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages) below to create `django.mo` in `locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/`:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

I got the error below even though I could create `django.po` and `django.mo` in `locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/`:

> ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

So following [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545202/french-translation-raises-valueerrorinvalid-token-in-plural-form-s-value#answer-61474435), in `django.po`, I replaced the code below:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=INTEGER; plural=EXPRESSION;\n"
```

With the code below:

```
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
```

Then, I ran `compilemessages` below again:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

But, I still got the error below:

> ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

Next, I removed `en_US` folder which has `django.po` and `django.mo` from both `locale/` folder and `django/conf/locale/` folder but I still got the error below:

> ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

Then, I ran `compilemessages` below again:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

But, I still got the error below:

> ValueError: invalid token in plural form: EXPRESSION

So, how can I solve the error?